# HTML 5 app to use buttons on phone using phonegap

Tags: android, html, cordova

I am trying to make a mobile app in html 5 using PhoneGap.
For this i am going to use button(like the menu button)
When i am searching in google i can find code, but it seems to me that only doesnt work for me.

My code so far from what i have tried(copied and not working):
http://pastebin.com/0U6ipFa7
Is there something wrong in the code?
Do i need to change something in the config so this will work?

Comment: have you insatlled phonegap plugins

Comment: No i didnt install any plugins, should i?

Answer (score 0):

`document.write()` can only be used when your script is inline with the HTML, for example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Foo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script language="javascript">
      document.write("bar");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In your case you should use `innerHTML`:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Foo</title>
    <script language="javascript">
      function onMenuKeyDown() {
        document.getElementById("barCntr").innerHTML += "<h1>Menu</h1>";
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="barCntr"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have tried what you said above, but all i see is a white, empty screen and nothing happening when i press a button(i tried all buttons), isn't there something in the config where i can enable/disable the function keys?

Answer (score 0):

Install phonegap/cordova [here](http://phonegap.com/install/) and even in Eclipse IDE install phone-gap plugin by going to help --->eclipse market

for getting menu option in the mobile on click on mobile option you are supposed to get like setting ,logout....

[menu option...](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2012/5/30/Example-of-adding-menu-support-to-a-PhoneGap-Application)

Answer (score 0):

You should install phonegap plugins first.

Follow this tutorial [here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/phonegap/phonegap-from-scratch/).

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
        document.addEventListener("menubutton", menuKeyDown, true);
    }, false);
    function menuKeyDown() {
            alert('Menu button pressed.');
        }
```

Refer [this](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#menubutton) phonegap link for reference.

Comment: I have tried what you said above, but all i see is a white, empty screen and nothing happening when i press a button(i tried all buttons).

Comment: Refer above PhoneGap link.